# JS: How to hide parent div with multiple nested divs, based on child div's content

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the code I'm looking at:

```
<div class="blotter_workshopitempublished blotter_entry">
    <div class="blotter_author_block">
        <div class="blotter_avatar_holder">
            <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/steam_profile_id">
                <div class="playerAvatar online">
                    <img src="https://steamcdn-a_medium.jpg" data-miniprofile="number">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/steam_profile_id" data-miniprofile="number">nickname</a>
            </div>
            <div>
            added an item to their favorites        </div>
        </div>
```

I'd like to hide all occurrences of "blotter_workshopitempublished blotter_entry" based on "steam_profile_id" or "nickname" (one or the other, I don't care, but "id" would be better), which are inside nested divs.

I looked at several other similar questions but still need help; I'll use this inside a Tampermonkey script.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should help:

```
const blotters = document.querySelectorAll('.blotter_workshopitempublished.blotter_entry');

blotters.forEach(blotter => {
    const id = blotter.querySelector('a').href.split('/').pop();
    if (id === "put whatever id you want to hide in here") {
        blotter.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, worked just fine. Do you also happen to know if I can make it work even after scrolling down the page, when new content gets loaded?

Comment: You can. I can't test this because you haven't provided the HTML, but something like this would do it:

`document.body.addEventListener("change", function() {
    // paste code here
});`

Comment: Sorry about the HTML but it's my Steam Activity Feed and I'd have to remove lots of stuff, so I don't really know how to do that. Anyway, I came up with this code but this time it doesn't even work anymore, all posts show up since the beginning.... [code](http://paste.debian.net/hidden/500d5daa/)

Comment: Ah okay. I can't test it because Steam is blocked at work, but I'll try it out on my own Steam activity feed later and see what the issue is. I'll comment again later when I have something :^)

Comment: Hey! So I did a little research on this and there's a whole thing called [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Example) that you'll need. I tested this in a Steam activity page using `document.body` as the target node. The console lit up as I scrolled. You might want to use `#ModalContentContainer` instead, though I'm not sure it'll report any less frequently. Anyway, you'll want to replace the contents of the `callback` function in the example above with the code I posted. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: It's a bit too complicated for me - tried but failed. Anyway it's not a big issue and I'm already grateful about original code.

Comment: No worries, it's pretty niche stuff. [Here's how you do it](https://pastebin.com/VAq3g7bt).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work here, @Darren. I copy pasted and added wanted "id" as in original code but nothing gets hidden ¯\_(ツ)_/¯